# Segmentation fault, listing contents of a directory

Tags: c++, c, unix, segmentation-fault

I am getting segmentation fault upon the end of a while loop(I am not sure if the error appears after termination or before).
I have checked that `dirlist_next_entry` successfully returns `DIRLIST_END` after
end of directory stream is reached. I don't understand what causes the fault as the loop should successfully terminate after end of stream is reached

```
#include "DirEntry.h"
#include <cstdio>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    if(argc != 2){
        printf("Directory not specified\n");
        return -1;
    }
    DirListError error;
    DirEntry result;
    handle hfile = dirlist_start_find(argv[1], &error);
    while( dirlist_next_entry(hfile, &result) != DIRLIST_END){
        printf("%s  %lld\n", result.entry, result.size);
    }
    dirlist_end_find(hfile);

}
```

Here is the definition of  `dirlist_next_entry`:

```
DirListError dirlist_next_entry(handle h, DirEntry* result){
    DIR* dirp = (DIR*)h; 
    dirent* dr;
    if((dr = readdir(dirp)) == NULL){
        return DIRLIST_END;
    }

        strcpy(result->entry, dr->d_name);
    if(dr->d_type == DT_DIR){
        result->is_directory = 1;
    }
    else if(dr->d_type == DT_REG){
        result->is_directory = 0;
        struct stat* buf;
        stat(result->entry, buf);
        result->size = buf->st_size;
    } 

    return DIRLIST_OK;  
}
```

`Direntry.h` is just a header with a couple of declarations:

```
#ifndef  DIRENTRY_H
#define DIRENTRY_H

const int MAX_PATH_LENGTH = 1024;
typedef void* handle;

struct DirEntry{
    char entry[MAX_PATH_LENGTH + 1];
    int is_directory;
    long long size;
};

enum DirListError{
    DIRLIST_OK,
    DIRECTORY_NOT_FOUND,
    INCORRECT_DIRECTORY_NAME,
    DIRLIST_END,
};

handle dirlist_start_find(const char* dir, DirListError* error);
DirListError dirlist_next_entry(handle h, DirEntry* result);
void dirlist_end_find(handle h);
#endif
```

Comment: What library is that. I vaguely remember seeing it before but I need a little memory jogging there. It's always a good idea to mention the things you're using (beyond the standard library)

Comment: What file system are you trying to read? ... ntfs has several gotchas? short cuts? weirdnesses? such that I abandoned the dir tree early for several issues.  I also do not recognize the lib your are using.  I used <dirent.h> on linux.

Comment: You take some minimal action on only 2 of the 8 d-types ... I would suggest that you should at least give a warning about detecting any of the other d-types, might be a clue in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely overwriting random memory:

```
struct stat* buf;
stat(result->entry, buf);
```

It should be:

```
struct stat buf;
stat(result->entry, &buf);
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the d_name field of dirent* is not null terminated. So strcpy() on this may lead to a segmentation fault later on. If this is the case you should use strncpy()

Comment: Are you able to identify which line is casing the segfault?